# Sum over dyadic interval with von Mangoldt function to sum over primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $1<c<2$ and write $\gamma=1/c$ so that $1/2<\gamma<1$. Now write $\lfloor u\rfloor=u-\psi(u)-1/2$ so that $\psi(u)=\{u\}-1/2$, where $\{u\}$ is the fractional part of $u$. We then denote by $\Lambda(n)$, the von Mangoldt function 
$$\Lambda(n)=\begin{cases} \log p & \text{ if } n=p^r \text{ for some prime } p \text{ and some integer } r\ge 1, \\
0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$
I want to show that if 
$$\sum_{x/2<n\le x}\Lambda(n)(\psi(-(n+1)^\gamma)-\psi(-n^\gamma))\ll x^{\gamma-\kappa}$$
for some $\kappa>0$ then 
$$\sum_{p\le x^c}(\psi(-(p+1)^\gamma)-\psi(-p^\gamma))\ll x^{1-\kappa'},$$
for some $\kappa'>0$; the sum is over primes $p\le x^c$. I presume this is an exercise in partial summation but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: I find your question weird. How did you come to that, what do you want to show

Comment: It is a preliminary step in the Piatetski-Shapiro prime number theorem. You can, for example, find it on page 4 of the paper 'Nombres premiers de la forme $\lfloor n^c\rfloor$' by Rivat and Sargos (2001).

Comment: Ok. Then it is just asking to say $\sum_{p\le x^c}(\psi(-(p+1)^\gamma)-\psi(-p^\gamma))\ll x^{1-\kappa'} $ iff $\sum_{p\le x^c}(\psi(-(p+1)^\gamma)-\psi(-p^\gamma))\log p \ll x^{1-\kappa'}\log x$ which is indeed a simple exercice of partial summation. And there are plenty of other proofs of the PNT.

Comment: In Graham & Kolesnik's book 'Van der Corput's Method of Exponential Sums', they say the following... 
"A simple argument using integration by parts shows that if $N'\le 2N$ and $F$ is bounded, then
$$\sum_{N<p<N'}F(p)\ll \frac1{\log N} \max_{N_1\le 2N}|\sum_{N<n\le N_1}\Lambda(n)F(n)|+N^{1/2}."$$
They then apply this to yield (essentially) the result in question.